# What causes this scratch?

Tags: service, paint-scratches, scratch

I have a Maruti White Baleno car. Today I left my car for servicing. They have did exterior dry cleaning, oil change etc. I see horizontal marks on back left fender (Attached screenshot) [image]

What might have caused it?

Answer (score 1):

Dirt or tar on whatever they were cleaning/drying with most likely.. it's hard to tell from the photo but it looks as if it could just be marks *on* the clear coat rather than actual scratches. That being the case I'd try cleaning it off with either a good tar remover or a gentle cutting polish such as Autoglym Super Resin Polish (I'd avoid going as far as T-cut, doubt you'll need something with that much abrasion)